# Reading binary data in memory into a stringstream and stream this over a socket

Tags: c++, memorystream, ostringstream

I would like to know if it is possible to, for instance, take a piece of data in memory, read it into an output stringstream (as binary data) and write this onto a socket for a client application to process.

The problem I run into while attempting this is the following:

Example:

```
char name[1024] = "Test";
std::ostringstream message (std::stringstream::out | std::stringstream::binary);

len = strlen(name);
message.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&len), sizeof(int));
message.write(test, len*sizeof(char));
```

I want to write this stringstream to the socket with all of the data in it, but the problem is this:  The stringstream write only executes the first time, in this case writing 4 (the length of the string) and none of the subsequent writes.  Am I missing something here?

If this is not the best way to do it, what would be the best way to accomplish this?  This is partly to reduce file I/O for cached memory snapshots.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please include a complete test case. For all we can tell, the `ostringstream` has buffered all the data, but your method of interpreting the buffer contents got stuck at the first NUL byte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code (with minor fixes) appears to [work](http://ideone.com/PycXGn) for me, so you might check to be sure that you are correctly handling the buffered binary data, i.e. you do not assume that the `std::string` contains a string.

Comment: @Potatoswatter..thanks for the reply and sorry for the delay in my reply.  
Yes, the problem was that one of the writers on the client side stopped at a null terminator in the string, that was part of the binary data.
I appreciate your help.